# Problem reading JTL file when we import JTL file to JMeter GUI

Tags: jmeter

I have executed a Jmeter load test from command line mode. It has created 95MB size of Jtl file.
When i try to browse this JTL from JMeter Gui. It returns, error loading JTL file.
In the logs, i get below error.
Can any one help us in this regard.

2021-03-15 11:55:55,068 WARN o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService: Insufficient columns to parse field 'Latency' at line 475165
2021-03-15 11:55:55,070 WARN o.a.j.r.ResultCollector: Problem reading JTL file: D:\test.jtl
org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterError: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 14 out of bounds for length 14
at org.apache.jmeter.save.CSVSaveService.makeResultFromDelimitedString(CSVSaveService.java:381) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]

Answer (score 0):

The error states that the number of columns in the .jtl file doesn't match JMeter's expectations.

If you executed your test on one JMeter instance and trying to open the .jtl file on another JMeter instance - make sure that [Results File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) is the same on both machines, the easiest option would be just copying `jmeter.properties` and `user.properties` files from the machine where you're running your tests to the machine where you're opening the results, alternatively you can use a form of the [diff](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html) tool to compare the files and detect the inconsistencies, once the results file configuration will be in sync - you should be able to open the file normally.

More information: [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

One more possible solution: you can generate the [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html) on the machine where you ran the test and copy the dashboard to the other machine

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have tried coping and replace files (User.properties & Jmeter.properties) from Slave to my local desktop. Import jtl file to aggregate report.  but still getting below error.            021-03-23 15:54:44,697 WARN o.a.j.s.CSVSaveService: Insufficient columns to parse field 'success' at line 651613
2021-03-23 15:54:44,697 WARN o.a.j.r.ResultCollector: Problem reading JTL file: C:\Users\TestPlan.jtl
org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterError: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 7 out of bounds for length 7. Same error with html report as well. any help ?

Comment: How do you get this .jtl file?

Comment: by executing JMeter from CLI in slave machine.                         
         jmeter -n -t testplan.jmx -l  "resultpath"